# Is it possible to add printers to Samba print server using Java?

Tags: java, printing, samba

I was searching for the possibility to add printers to Samba Share programmatically to use them in the future but found nothing. Or maybe Samba is not intended for such purposes. What do you think?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, Samba is not intended for such purposes.